# Qlikview: Multiple Columns of table

Tags: multiple-columns, qlikview

Is it possible to have a table be divided in multiple columns after a certain number of rows is reached?

```
+----+----+
| A  |  1 |
| B  |  2 |
| C  |  3 |
| D  |  4 |
+----+----+
```

Will this transform in to :

```
+----+----+   +----+----+
| A  |  1 |   | C  |  3 |
| B  |  2 |   | D  |  4 |
+----+----+   +----+----+
```

Comment: Do you need this in the data model or UI?

Comment: I would like it in my straight table object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think that you could do it in one object. The associativity of the dimensions wouldn't allow A and C to be on the same line.

You can use this logic to expose a hidden straight table every time the limit is exceeded, so you would have to create and place as many objects as you would need. (Creating a new one would require lots of macro coding and that's not my wheelhouse)

The theory is;

1. Create a numeric ID for each distinct value of the dimension in the script;

   `load *, 
     autonumber(DIMENSION) as DIMENSIONID
     from (DATASOURCE)` will work if a numeric ID doesn't already exist
2. In the expressions tab you need to create an expression that uses set analysis and the ranking capabilities of the `min()` function to show only the group of values below the group threshold in each object;

   object 1 expression: `sum({<DIMENSIONID={$(=min(DIMENSIONID,1))}>} VALUE) + sum({<DIMENSIONID={$(=min(DIMENSIONID,2))}>} VALUE)`

   object 2 expression: `sum({<DIMENSIONID={$(=min(DIMENSIONID,3))}>} VALUE) + sum({<DIMENSIONID={$(=min(DIMENSIONID,4))}>} VALUE)`. (You could use fancier set analysis to do min(y) in only one statement but I'm not going to since it's only 2 lines per object.)
3. Use the conditional show to expose the next object when the limit is reached;

   First object will always show. Second object needs something like this in the Layout Tab->Show->Conditional `count(DISTINCT DIMENSION)>2`

Comment: I am very new to Qlikview, so i don't really know where to put steps 1 and 2